# Check if NSTimeInterval equals 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
//Gets the time right now
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

//Stores the difference in seconds between when the test was started and now.
NSTimeInterval interval = [self.expires timeIntervalSinceDate:now];

if (interval == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Any reason why the condition wont be true?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `NSTimeInterval` is only a `double`, you might have floating point rounding error. Try using something like

```
if (abs(interval) < EPS) {
```

where `EPS` is a small enough constant.

Or, if you want to know seconds and not milliseconds, you can truncate that double to int.

But judging from your code, I think you might want to check if timeline has **already expired**, not that it expires at this exact moment. Probability of the later is very small. This should do the trick.

```
if (interval < 0) {
```